# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Chemistry breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         14
Users destroyed                                 183          0
Users deleted                                     9          0
Users contacted                                  17          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           363      4,706
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               61      1,984
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        345      4,034
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               28      1,017
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                80      6,487
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              174     21,519
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          3
Tag synonyms created                              2          0
Revisions redacted                                6          0
Questions unprotected                             2          0
Questions reopened                              157         30
Questions protected                              37         53
Questions migrated                                9          3
Questions merged                                 15          0
Questions flagged⁴                               21      2,611
Questions closed                                648      4,661
Question flags handled⁴                         542      2,090
Posts unlocked                                    5          7
Posts undeleted                                  47        146
Posts locked                                     19        229
Posts deleted⁵                                1,321      6,471
Posts bumped                                      0      1,594
Escalations to the CM team                        6          0
Comments undeleted                              141          0
Comments flagged                                979      3,308
Comments deleted⁶                             6,466      3,780
Comment flags handled                         3,741        546
Bounties canceled                                 2          0
Answers flagged                                 281      3,040
Answer flags handled                          2,618        703
All comments on a post moved to chat             30          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...